# travis mysql database create user error

Tags: mysql, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I wanted to set up travis for my spring-boot project where I use user makler/makler for accessing database. When running travis I get an error saying:

```
$ mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE stockmarket;'

$ mysql -u root -e 'CREATE USER 'makler'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'makler';'
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'makler' at line 1


The command "mysql -u root -e 'CREATE USER 'makler'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'makler';'" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

My travis.yml file looks like:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
services:
  - mysql
dist: trusty
sudo: required
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - mysql-server-5.6
    - mysql-client-core-5.6
    - mysql-client-5.6
before_script:
  - mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE stockmarket;'
  - mysql -u root -e 'CREATE USER 'makler'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'makler';'
  - mysql -u root -e 'GRANT ALL ON stockmarket.* TO 'makler'@'localhost';'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its the quotes surrounding the query. Update your before_script to surround the queries using double quotes(") instead of single quotes(')

```
before_script:
- mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE stockmarket;'
- mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'makler'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'makler';"
- mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL ON stockmarket.* TO 'makler'@'localhost';"
```

Build worked fine after I changed it and ran the build on travis. Hope this helps.